# How to make facebook app allow requests from django project that runs on a local server?

Tags: python, django, facebook, authentication, oauth

I am trying to use [django social auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) to auth via facebook.
I used [this](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) documentation to make changes in my django project and to create and setup the facebook app. I am running django project on local server. The project has url `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. When hit the following link on my project's web page:

**Template**

```
<p><a href="{% url "socialauth_begin" "facebook" %}">Facebook</a></p>
```

**Rendered template**

```
<p><a href="/accounts_social/login/facebook/">Facebook</a></p>
```

it redirects me to a facebook page where I can see the following message:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more
>   of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match
>   the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of
>   one of the App's domains.

How to change facebook app's settings to allow 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000`?

**upd**

Added `localhost` to app domains and `http://localhost:8000/` to site URL in my fb app's settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook app doesn't allow IP addresses like that, but it does allow `localhost`. In the App Domains on the Settings tab you need to add `localhost`. What sucks is that other services (such as twitter) don't accept localhost and you can only use 127.0.0.1:8000, which means you have to switch back and forth.

It works for local development, but it's not pretty.

EDIT:
You also need to add `http://localhost:8000/` to the Site URL first

Comment: Unable to add `localhost`: "This must be derived from Secure Canvas URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: localhost"

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко check the edit, forgot to mention you need to add the Site URL first.